# Adding/Appending Dynamic Database (SQL) Select Box on Button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

i found the below fiddle from net very useful. (i am not able to post the code due to format error)

[Please click here to see the code](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/2/)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="data1" value="abc" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" onClick="addRow(this)">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
var txtbox = '<tr><td><select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option   
value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option   
value="audi">Audi</option></select></td></td>';

function addRow(btn) {
    $(btn).closest('table').append(txtbox);
}
```

While clicking the **Add** button,
It is creating new **select box** dynamically 
in the above code has the **hard coded CAR values**, 
but i need to get the **value** of the **cars from the database table**

could you please help...?

Regards,
Jeena

Comment: You need to make a trip to the server to fetch it. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: as @Diodeus mentioned, you need to get it from the server, or let the server write it there instead, var txtbox= <?php getCarsSelectBox() ?> for example

Answer (score 0):

You should post to your php file and get from it source and then print it on ur div as below.

ur js file:

```
function addRow(btn) {

    $.post("cars.php",function(data){

    $(btn).closest('table').append(data);

   });
}
```

ur php file:

```
$a = mysql_query("select * from cars");

echo '<tr><td><select>';

while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {

echo '<option value="'.$b['id'].'">'.$b['brand'].'</option>';

}

echo '</select></td></td>';
```

Take it easy

Comment: Thanks for the help.i could do it. i need to collect the values from the list box and save it to a database on button click. how will i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

get your selectbox value with id

`<select id="my_select"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>`

on your js :

`function addRow(btn) {

var select_val = $('#my_select').val();

```
$.post("cars.php",{select_val:select_val},function(data){

alert(data);
```

});
}`

on your php file:

```
<?php 

$select_val = $_POST['select_val'];

//db_process

?>
```